# How to get linux screen title from command line

Tags: python, gnu-screen

How can I fetch the title of a `screen` session from the command line?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Kristian. To conform with the structure of the site, please rephrase the problem in the form of a question, and then post your solution below.

Comment: I've edited your post for you. Cut out everything below the horizontal line, and paste it into an answer in the box below.

Comment: also, please remove the "linux" tag and text. This isn't specific to Linux

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a very small and simple python script with `pexpect` to do it.

It is handy in multiuser environments where some host is reserved and status is written to screen title by user.
It works for me, feel free to make it better.
In order to fetch specific session title, you need to modify the script and call for correct session.

If you run this through remote connection as local script (through SSH for example), remember to set `export TERM=xterm` before execution.

```
try:
    import pexpect
    import sys
    child=pexpect.spawn('screen -x')
    child.sendcontrol('a');
    child.send('A');
    i = child.expect('Set window.*')
    child.sendcontrol('c');
    child.sendcontrol('a');
    child.send('d');
    TITLE=str(child.after)
    TITLE_P=TITLE.split('7m')
    if str(TITLE_P[-1]) == '':
        print 'Title not found'
    else:
        print str(TITLE_P[-1])
except:
    print 'Could not check screen Title'
```